# C# Converting List throwing exception in linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a problem about list to list problem.

My Models:

```
public partial class OrderDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string SparePartName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SparePartPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Labor { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Total { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public partial class Orders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int StorageId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateEntry { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateRelease { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateEstimatedRelease { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateUpdate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string FollowCode { get; set; }
    public string DeviceBrand { get; set; }
    public string DeviceModel { get; set; }
    public string DeviceSerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string DeviceComplaint { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class VMOrderEdit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StorageId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string StorageName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerTelephone { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateEntry { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateUpdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateRelease { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateEstimatedRelease { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    public string FollowCode { get; set; }
    public string DeviceBrand { get; set; }
    public string DeviceModel { get; set; }
    public string DeviceSerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string DeviceComplaint { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public List<VMOrderEditDetails> Details { get; set; }
}
public class VMOrderEditDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string SparePartName { get; set; }
    public decimal SparePartPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Labor { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
List<VMOrderEdit> OrderEditObj = (from o in DB.Orders
                                  join sn in DB.OrderStatusName on o.Status equals sn.Id
                                  join st in DB.Storages on o.StorageId equals st.Id
                                  join c in DB.Customers on o.CustomerId equals c.Id
                                  where o.Id == Id
                                  select new VMOrderEdit()
                                  {
                                      Id = o.Id,
                                      StorageId = o.StorageId,
                                      StorageName = st.Name,
                                      UserId = o.UserId,
                                      CustomerName = c.NameSurname,
                                      CustomerTelephone = c.Telephone,
                                      DateEntry = o.DateEntry,
                                      DateUpdate = o.DateUpdate,
                                      DateRelease = o.DateRelease,
                                      Price = o.Price,
                                      StatusName = sn.Name,
                                      FollowCode = o.FollowCode,
                                      DeviceBrand = o.DeviceBrand,
                                      DeviceModel = o.DeviceModel,
                                      DeviceSerialNumber = o.DeviceSerialNumber,
                                      DeviceComplaint = o.DeviceComplaint,
                                      Comment = o.Comment,
                                      Details = DB.OrderDetail.Where(x => x.OrderId == o.Id).ToList()
                                      }
                               ).ToList();
```

on this line:

```
Details = DB.OrderDetail.Where(x => x.OrderId == o.Id).ToList()
```

visual studio gives this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List

how can i handle this error ?

Comment: `Details` is a `VMOrderEditDetails` list while  `DB.OrderDetail` is (i'm assuming) an `OrderDetail` enumerable.

Comment: The question is, what 'OrderDetails' do you want to store in 'Details', then do a nested select to populate the 'Details' property, then ToList()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
Details = DB.OrderDetail.Where(x => x.OrderId == o.Id)
            .Select(x => new VMOrderEditDetails {
                       Id = x.Id,
                       OrderId = x.OrderId,
                       SparePartName = x.SparePartName,
                       SparePartPrice = x.SparePartPrice.Value,
                       Labor = x.Labor.Value,
                       Total = x.Total.Value,
                       Comment = x.Comment
                   }).ToList()
```

Comment: Thnak you for your effort and time.

Comment: @ysrtymz, x.Labor is nullable type and requires x.Labor.Value but answer marked as accepted above for without .value?

Comment: i figured it out. thank you for warning. i updated my ViewModel with "decimal?"

Answer (score 2):

The DB returns an object of `OrderDetails` but the items in the `Details` list property is of type `VMOrderEditDetails`..

You **must** convert each item from `OrderDetails` to `VMOrderEditDetails` before assigning.

1. You can add a .`Select` after the `.Where` to convert to that type just before the `.ToList()` in the row with the exception *(see in code of option 2)*.

   ```
   Details = DB.OrderDetail.Where(x => x.OrderId == o.Id)
                           .Select(x => new VMOrderEditDetails { /* your conversion*/})
                           .ToList()
   ```
2. A better solution will be to add an extra `GroupJoin` before that and then to just have the conversion in the `.Select` and not also the retrieving of the data:

   ```
   List<VMOrderEdit> OrderEditObj = (from o in DB.Orders
                                     join sn in DB.OrderStatusName on o.Status equals sn.Id
                                     join st in DB.Storages on o.StorageId equals st.Id
                                     join c in DB.Customers on o.CustomerId equals c.Id
                                     join d in DB.OrderDetails on o.Id equals d.OrderId into d 
                                     where o.Id == Id
                                     select new VMOrderEdit()
                                     {
                                         Id = o.Id,
                                         StorageId = o.StorageId,
                                         //All the other properties
                                         Comment = o.Comment,
                                         Details = d.Select(x => new VMOrderEditDetails{ /*your convertion*/ }).ToList()
                                     }).ToList();
   ```
3. And because you are using Entity Framework an even better option is
   to replace all the `join`s with the use of Navigation Properties, and then still to have the conversion at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for efort and time.

Comment: @ysrtymz - you are welcome :) Did it help you understand the problem?

Comment: yes clearly.
i was try to use a list object that didnt recognized/called/created.. right?

Answer (score 2):

Your'e trying to assign a list of `OrderDetail` to `VMOrderEditDetails` which is bound to fail.

Your LINQ query should be something as follows. I haven't done the nullable checks and conversions on the Select. It can be done by you and is pretty straightforward. Please mark as answer if it helps.

```
 Details = DB.OrderDetail.Where(x => x.OrderId == o.Id).Select(x=>new VMOrderEditDetails{
    Id = x.Id,
    OrderId = x.OrderId,
    SparePartName = x.SparePartName,
    SparePartPrice = x.SparePartPrice,
    Labor = x.Labor,
    Total = x.Total,
    Comment = x.Comment
}).ToList()
```

Comment: Thnak you for your effort and time.

Answer (score 1):

```
DB.OrderDetail
  .Where(x => x.OrderId == o.Id)
  .ToList()
```

should be

```
DB.OrderDetail
  .Where(x => x.OrderId == o.Id)
  .Select(x => new VMOrderEditDetails () 
  { 
      Id = x.OrderId
  })
  .ToList<VMOrderEditDetails>()
```

as the `types` are different

Answer (score 0):

`Details` is a `List<VMOrderEditDetails>` type but you are trying to assign it a `List<OrderDetail>` value so  make it like this

```
Details = DB.VMOrderEditDetails.Where(x => x.OrderId == o.Id).ToList()
```

Comment: DB.VMOrderEditDetails certainly doesn't exist, as VMOrderEditDetails  is a ViewModel class.